# listview consisting of checkboxes

Tags: android

I have a layout for a listview consisting of a single checkbox per row. 
When the activity is started, it displays the checkboxes with some of them checked by default.
Initially, i get the correctly checked checkboxes. But when i want to uncheck some and check others,
all of them get unchecked after i get the message 'You cannot have more than 5 choices!' from the custom adapter.
I want to be able to check new boxes or uncheck some of those already checked from the start.
The total number of checked boxes should be less than 5.

layout: **single_row_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cinteretidtxt"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Custom adapter: **ModCinteretsAdapter**

```
public class ModCinteretsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ModCinteret>{
    private ArrayList<String> selectedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> selectedids = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ModCinteretsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ModCinteret> cinterets) {
        super(context, 0, cinterets);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        ModCinteret cinteret = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_row_item, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        final TextView cinteretidtxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cinteretidtxt);
        cinteretidtxt.setText(cinteret.getId());
        final CheckBox cinterettxt = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        cinterettxt.setText(cinteret.getText());

        if((cinteret.getFlag()).equals("1")) {
            cinterettxt.setChecked(true);
            selectedStrings.add(cinterettxt.getText().toString());
            selectedids.add(cinteretidtxt.getText().toString());
        }else {
            cinterettxt.setChecked(false);
            selectedStrings.remove(cinterettxt.getText().toString());
            selectedids.remove(cinteretidtxt.getText().toString());
        }
        cinterettxt.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    if(selectedStrings.size()<5) {
                        selectedStrings.add(cinterettxt.getText().toString());
                        selectedids.add(cinteretidtxt.getText().toString());
                    }else{
                        cinterettxt.setChecked(false);
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"You cannot have more than 5 choices!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    selectedStrings.remove(cinterettxt.getText().toString());
                    selectedids.remove(cinteretidtxt.getText().toString());
                }

            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSelectedString(){
        return selectedStrings;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSelectedId(){
        return selectedids;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi you should not add click listener inside getView. The views get recycled and everything will be mixed up.

Comment: hi Jawad. I  think it is perfectly ok to have click  listener inside getView. I read some examples from the net

Comment: Maybe I did not know. When do you update the flags of cinteret?

Comment: the flags are set in the activity holding the listview

Comment: So each time the listview gets redrawn this code will execute since you never update these flags.  cinterettxt.setChecked(true);
            selectedStrings.add(cinterettxt.getText().toString());
            selectedids.add(cinteretidtxt.getText().toString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a global static variable in your adapter.

```
static int nbChecked = 5;
```

In your ModCinteret add a boolean.

```
boolean isChecked;
```

Instead of using your flags, add.

```
if(cinteret.getIsChecked()){
    cinterettxt.setChecked(true);
}
else{
    cinterettxt.setChecked(false);
}
```

Finally in your listener change onCheckedChanged to:

```
if(!isChecked){
    cinteret.setIsChecked(false);
    nbChecked--;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
else{
    if(nbChecked == 5){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"You cannot have more than 5 choices!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        cinteret.setIsCheck(true);
        nbChecked++;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I think it should do it.

Comment: And When you create your listview, set your cinteret.checked state to false except for your defaults.

Comment: I still have the same problem. I want to be able to get the get the list of checked boxes from  the activity where the listview is declared

Answer (score 0):

Store the state of the each checkbox in an Array

Declare an boolean Array and Use index to store the value of particular Chekcbox

and set Defaults to your checkbox Based on That

```
SparseBooleanArray sba=new SparseBooleanArray();
```